# How to revert SVN commit on wrong branch without losing history

Tags: svn, merge

I just screwed up and need to figure out how to revert several commits without destroying everything.

I am trying to merge `branch1` and `branch2` in a temporary branch like so:

```
1)  svn cp ^/branch1 ^/branch1a  // Create a branch
2)  svn sw ^/branch1a            // Switch to that branch
3)  svn merge ^/branch2 .        // Merge branch2 to branch1a
4)  <do lots of manual work>
5)  svn ci .                     // revision 991,994,995, return to step 4 if needed
6)  svn sw ^/branch1             // When happy, switch back to branch1
7)  svn merge ^/branch1a .       // Merge our happy changes back into branch1
8)  svn ci                       // Commit these changes
```

I'm still iterating around steps 4-5, but realized that I forgot to do step 2. I need to revert my revisions from `branch1`, and apply them to `branch1a` so I can continue work.

I tried to do a revert with `svn merge -c991,994,995 .`, but my working copy seemed to be unchanged.  Also, I need to ensure that I can keep these changes and re-apply them in `branch1a`.  What is a sequence of commands I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using TortoiseSVN to accomplish this. Instructions are mostly here:
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

1. Ensure your working copy is clean and on `branch1`
2. Open the `log` dialogue
3. Select the revisions you don't like (shift-click for range, ctrl-click of
   individual revs)
4. Right click and select "Revert changes from these revisions". This will revert your working copy.
5. `svn ci .` to commit the changes to the repo (this is rev 997)
6. `svn sw ^/branch1a` to get back to the intended branch
7. `svn merge -c 991,994,995 .` to bring the reverted changes here
8. `svn ci .` to commit the revisions to the repo.

I'm just a little worried that when it comes time to merge `branch1a` back into `branch1`, revision 997 will get in the way and prevent a good merge.  If someone gives a good answer of a good resolution, I'll be happy to select that answer over this one (which is partial until I actually get to import the revs).